# Insert image into varbinary(max) column from Azure Storage into Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, unity-game-engine, storage, bulk

As the title suggests I'm trying to add an image from Azure Bulk Storage and put that into a VarBinary(Max) column in my Azure SQL Database.

I'm building an application in Unity where each user has a logo. This logo is specific to each user. I send a web request through to PHP code which then requests the server for the information I need from the specific database. So I'm trying to find a way to ensure each user (row in the table) has a logo attatched to it. I'm thinking if it's not right to store images in the database itself then would it be possible to do a web request to a URL that is stored in the logo column, to then draw the image from that URL and use that in the application? If so, does anyone know how I would do this?

I know the Bulk Storage provides a URL to the image. Additionally, if possible I want to add it into currently created rows. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? IMHO a better approach would be to store binary data in Blob Storage and keep the blob URL in database. It will be a cheaper and more efficient solution.

Comment: How would I reference that image though? Lets say its like Facebook and each person in the table has a display picture, how would you be able to grab that picture and ensure it goes to the right persons account without needing to hardcode it each time? That's why I thought storing it in a database would be a good option.

Comment: Each item (user image in your case) in blob storage has a unique URL. You could simply fetch the image URL from the database and use that as src attribute in your img tag (assuming you're building a web application). May I suggest you edit your question and include more details about what you want to accomplish. Someone here can suggest a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions :
You have user icons stored as blobs in your Azure Storge account with anonymous read access at Blob level
Blob URL is https://my-az.blob.core.windows.net/usericon/staff icon.png
(Replace 'my-az'with your specific Azure tenant name)
You have two separate tables - UserDets and UserImg. It is always better to have the image data in a separate table.

In SSMS execute this command -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyUserAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://my-az.blob.core.windows.net/usericon');
```

Then insert the image into VARBINARY column -

```
Insert into UserImg (UserId, UserImg) 
(Select 1, BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( 
BULK 'staff icon.png', 
DATA_SOURCE = 'MyUserAzureBlobStorage', SINGLE_BLOB) AS ImageFile);
```

If you are using credentials for blob access, there are some additional steps. But it is not required in current instance.